# FileReader can't find R Script

Tags: r, maven, javafx, filereader, renjin

I try run my R Script within JavaFx. I use Renjin for this purpose and it seems to work properly with statements I run internally. But I want to run an external R Script. The project is set up with Maven so the path should be easy as the R Script is in the resources folder. The path works when I load FXML files, so I'm pretty confused why it can't find my Script.

Here's a short example:

```
package survey;

import javax.script.*;
import org.renjin.script.*;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class calcFunction {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // create a script engine manager:
    RenjinScriptEngineFactory factory = new RenjinScriptEngineFactory();
    // create a Renjin engine:
    ScriptEngine engine = factory.getScriptEngine();

    engine.put("x", 4);
    engine.put("y", 5);

    engine.eval(new FileReader("/test.R"));
  }

}
```

Is something missing? Thanks in advance!

EDIT1:

With my FXML files it works with the "/" path like this:

```
 root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/moduleDa.fxml"));
```

EDIT2:

Someone who deleted his comment proposed this:

```
engine.eval(new FileReader(new File(".").getAbsolutePath()+"/test.R"));
```

It works if the script is in the root directory, where the pom.xml file is located. @James_D made it work so the R script can be located in the resources folder - thanks a lot!

Comment: The reason is that the path is wrong. It’s rather unlikely that you have an R script residing at the root path of your file system (`"/"`).

Comment: @Konrad Rudoph I thought you can get to the resources folder in Maven based project by typing "/"? It works fine with my FXML files (see EDIT).

Comment: @jeypeu There is a difference between getClass().getResource(„/...“) and new FileReader(„/…“).
getResource() is looking in your jar and new FileReader on your file system, you can try new FileReader(new File(this.getClass().getResource("/test.R").toURI())); but there should be better was doing this

Comment: You're not loading your FXML files with a file reader, though, you're loading them with the `FXMLLoader`, which expects a `URL`, not the path to a file. If your R script is part of the resources folder (i.e. it is being bundled as part of the application) it won't even be a file when you deploy the application - it will be an entry in the jar file.

Comment: @jeypeu This is unrelated to the file type (i.e. it doesn’t work with FXML either!). It’s just that the APIs are confusing, and use the same type (`String`) to represent different things (in one case, a file system location; in the other case, a Java/JAR resource URI). Read the respective documentations of the `Class.getResource` method and the `FileReader` constructor).

Comment: @James_D Do you have any suggestion where to locate the file, if I want it to work in the deployed application?

Comment: @James_D Mainly because their [documentation](http://docs.renjin.org/en/latest/library/evaluating.html) proposed it (at the bottom). They don't want to deploy an application, though. How else shall I do it? Do you have any sources where i can read myself into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your R script is bundled as part of the application, it can't be treated as a file - you need to treat it as a resource. Typically, you will deploy your application as a Jar file, and the resources will be elements within that jar file (they won't be files in their own right).

So just treat the R script as a resource and load it as such. I don't know the renjin framework, but I assume `ScriptEngine` here is a `javax.script.ScriptEngine`, in which case [`ScriptEngine.eval(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html#eval-java.io.Reader-) takes a `Reader` as a parameter, and so (if your R script is located in the root of the class path) you can do

```
engine.eval(new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/test.R")));
```